# Python - Split list to multiple lists with respect to a keyword

Tags: python-3.x, list, split, k-means, data-mining

I have this huge python list I got as an output from a K means Clustering algorithm. Here is the code.

```
clusterlist = []
for i in range(true_k):
clusterlist.append('\nCluster %d:' % i),
for ind in order_centroids[i]:
    clusterlist.append('%s' % terms[ind])
```

Here , the string "Cluster %d" value is appended to the list when a new cluster starts. I want to split this final clusterlist into mutiple lists based on the keyword "Cluster" or can it be indeed stored into multiple lists rather than a single clusterlist ?. Here is the sample output list:

```
['\nCluster 0:', 'need', 'zize6kysq2', 'fleming', 'finale', 'finally', 'finals', 'fined', 'finisher', 'firepower', 'fit', 'fitness', 'flaw', 'flaws', 'flexibility', 'ground', 'fluffed', 'fluke', 'fn0uegxgss', 'focussed', 'foot', 'forget', 'forgot', 'form', 'format', 'forward', 'fought', 'final', 'filter', 'figures', 'fight', 'fascinating', 'fashioned', 'fast', 'fastest', 'fat', 'fatigue', 'fault', 'fav', 'featured', 'feel', 'feeling', '\nCluster 1:', 'feels', 'fees', 'feet', 'felt', 'ferguson', 'fewest', 'ffc4pfbvfr', 'ffs', 'field', 'fielder', 'fielders', 'fielding', 'fow', 'fow_hundreds', 'frame', 'gingers', 'gives', 'giving', 'glad', 'glenn', 'gloves', 'god', 'gods', 'goes', 'going', 'gois','\nCluster 2:', 'gon', 'gone', 'good', 'got', 'grand', 'grandhomme', 'grandmom', 'grandpa', 'grass']
```

[I tried this SO solution using the following code but it didn't work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329118/python-split-a-list-into-multiple-lists-based-on-a-subset-of-elements)

```
import more_itertools as mit
result = list(mit.split_at(clusterlist, pred=lambda x: set(x) & {"Cluster"}))
```

It gave the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Please provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the expected output, how your final `result` list should look?please provide an expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use list of lists to store the clusters:

```
clusterlists = []
for i in range(true_k):
    dummy_list  = []
    for ind in order_centroids[i]:
        dummy_list.append('%s' % terms[ind])
    clusterlists.append(dummy_list)
```

Here the clusterlists will store clusters and you can reach them with indices.

Answer (score 1):

Iterative solution (expecting list to start with a cluster item):

```py
d = {}
for item in a: 
    if item.startswith("\nCluster"): 
        current_cluster = item[1:-1]  # cut \n and : from cluster name 
        d[current_cluster] = []
    else: 
        d[current_cluster].append(i)
```